# How to use multiple timezone on grafana

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grafana

I have open this post today but some of rules i need to delete for recreate.

Summarize,
I have grafa 9.3.6 running on rhel 7.9.
My dashboard has 2 different data source.

1.) Influxdb

2.) Sql server

My panels which querying data shows correct time but sql server data source show time +2 hours as you see below.

Both server using same ntp.

My question is as you see below when i exec query on ssms query show correct time which is 19:36
[image]

But when i execute on grafana output show +2 hour which is 21:36
[image]

Comment: please also the timezones that are currently in place https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timezone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16  which ould be more intersting than the times

Comment: my timezon is GTB Standard Time

Comment: and both show that?

Comment: yes both is same

Comment: sql server Datetime doesn't save the time zone and grafana uses the timezone of the webbrowser https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/organization-preferences/  there you find how you can change it

Comment: yes you are right. If i change timezone for dashboard for example from Nicosia to UTC my problem fixing. But that time another panels which is querying from influxdb time is begin to be mistake.

Comment: the usal way if you have different timezone is to safe t in utc, so that the default would not matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252474/discussion-between-microracle-and-nbk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way which fixed in query level.
Firstly i have tried switchoffset function but didnt worked.
Then i used dateadd as below and its worked perfectly.

```
 DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETDATE(), GETutcDATE()), datestamp)
```